# Как в связке nginx - Symfony прописать символьную ссылку на phpmyadmin чтобы Symfony ее не обрабатывала?

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, symfony

Подскажите как правильно прописывать ссылки на сервере если после установки симфони у нее путь

```
root  /var/www/html/symfony5/
```

Но при этом на главной странице сайта открывается папка

```
root  /var/www/html/symfony5/public/
```

Ставлю PhpMyAdmin. Он по идее ставится по пути

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Как мне теперь сделать чтобы его index.php открывался по ccылке site.com/phpmyadmin?

Во всех примерах есть установка символьной ссылки:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Но так не работает. Ни так:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /usr/share/nginx/html/symfony5
```

Как запустить файлы phpadmina? Или как например я могу настроить несколько разных проектов site.com/1, site.com/2 и т.д. чтобы Symfony не думала что это ее роуты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если phpMyadmin лежит в папке `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` и вы хотите чтобы он открывался по URL `/phpmyadmin`, то вы должны создать в конфиге nginx для соответствующего блока `server` такой location

```
location = /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php;
    .... далее fastcgi_pass на php ....
}
```

И обечпечить чтобы у пользователей, под которыми работают сервисы nginx и php, был доступ к скриптам в папке /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!. А где править конфиг по пути nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ? Уже совсем запутался. У меня файлы phpmyadmin лежат и по пути /etc/nginx/sites-available и по пути /usr/share/phpmyadmin то же самое.... на какой путь надо ставить? И куда вобще ставит команда sudo apt install phpmyadmin? в какой каталог?

Comment: В /etc/nginx/nginx.conf лежит главный конфиг и в него чаще всего инклудируются другие файлы например из папки /etc/nginx/conf.d. Этот location должен быть размещен в любом месте блока ```server``` отвечающего за ваш хост

Comment: Два дня подключаю не работает... Нашел еще файл /etc/nginx/sites-available# nano phpmyadmin.conf. Вроде уже с прописаной конфигурацией. От куда он взялся? Может его инклудить в /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ? Или он и так с этой папки читается? После каждой правки я выполняю команды nginx -t
nginx -s reload

Comment: в выоде команды nginx -V посмотрите какой конфиг используется и дале смотрите что в него инклудится

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась тем что по удалял все лишние конфиги, оставил только официальный конфиг Symfony 5 (в котором убрал фразу internal; и поправил на такой location ~* .php(/|$) {).
Потом все заработало. Но все таки создал на поддомене PhpMyAdmin. Для этого у регистратора делаем новый поддомен, на сервер по пути "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled" добавляем конфиг имя поддомена.conf с содержимым (меняются данные на ваш поддомен)

```
server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;
 server_name xx.xxx.ua www.xx.xxx.ua;

 root  /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
 index index.html index.php;

 client_max_body_size 100M;

 location = /favicon.ico {
     log_not_found off;
     access_log off;
 }


# optionally disable falling back to PHP script for the asset directories;
# nginx will return a 404 error when files are not found instead of passing the
# request to Symfony (improves performance but Symfony's 404 page is not displayed)
# location /bundles {
#     try_files $uri =404;
# }

location ~* \.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}

# return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
# this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;}
```

Потом PhpMyAdmin откроется по ссылке вашего поддомена.